# Display which radio button is selected after form is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I am quite new to PHP and I am  currently making a survey. Users select answers to questions in the form on radio buttons. Each question has 4 possibilities and are grouped under each question. When the form is submitted, a page should show which button on each group was selected. The code at the moment is this:

```
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
  <p>How easy would you say it is to create new carers?</p>
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup1" value="rg1v1"> Excellent
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup1" value="rg1v2"> Good
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup1" value="rg1v3"> Average
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup1" value="rg1v4"> Poor</br>

  <p>How easy is it to generate a report?</p>
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup2" value="rg2v1"> Excellent
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup2" value="rg2v2"> Good
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup2" value="rg2v3"> Average
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup2" value="rg2v4"> Poor</br>

  <p>How easy is it to add and alter timesheets?</p>
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup3" value="excellent"> Excellent
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup3" value="good"> Good
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup3" value="average"> Average
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup3" value="poor"> Poor</br>

  <p>How good would you rate the Packages Of Care functions? </p>
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup4" value="excellent"> Excellent
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup4" value="good"> Good
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup4" value="average"> Average
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup4" value="poor"> Poor</br>

  <p>Question 5</p>
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup5" value="excellent"> Excellent
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup5" value="good"> Good
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup5" value="average"> Average
   <input type="radio" name="rgroup5" value="poor"> Poor</br>
   </br>
      Please  Enter Your Comments Below:
   </br></br>
        <textarea name="comments" width="100px" rows="4" cols="50" wrap="wrap"></textarea>
   </br></br>
        <input type="submit">
   <br/><br/>
</form>
```

and my PHP for the "thankyou.php" page is:

```
<?php 

switch($_POST['rgroup1']) {
    case "rg1v1":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg1v2":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg1v3":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg1v4":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 1";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup2']) {
    case "rg2v1":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg2v2":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg2v3":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg2v4":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 2";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup3']) {
    case "rg3v1":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v2":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v3":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v4":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 3";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup4']) {
    case "rg4v1":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v2":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v3":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v4":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 4";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup5']) {
    case "rg5v1":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v2":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v3":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v4":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 5";
}


echo $value;
echo $value2;
echo $value3;
echo $value4;
echo $value5;

?>
```

I am getting a error saying I am not defining the variables for value2, 3, 4 and 5 and I am not sure why.

Comment: please copy paste exact the error you got. i didnt get you correctly.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: value3 in C:\wamp\www\thankyou.php on line 106

Same for values on 2 and 4 and 5

Comment: @RossDoughty: a suggestion, if all your radio button group values are same throughout don't repeat the switch, instead use a loop.And if you want to show the checked radio button in thankyou page just echo checked inside radio button.And for case put the values in the radio button group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3, 4, and 5 the `radio` section values are excellent, good, average, poor and not working. 'rg3v1', 'rg3v2', 'rg3v3', and 'rg3v4'. So when execution goes into the following code,

```
switch($_POST['rgroup3']) {
    case "rg3v1":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v2":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v3":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v4":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 3";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup4']) {
    case "rg4v1":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v2":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v3":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v4":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 4";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup5']) {
    case "rg5v1":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v2":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v3":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v4":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 5";
}
```

it didn't assign anything and shows an error when you try to print the following variables,

```
echo $value3;
echo $value4;
echo $value5;
```

Answer (score 1):

for rgroups 3,4 and 5 your values are not in the expected format as rgroup1 and rgroup2. you have put your values as strings like excellent,good, etc. which do not match with your switch cases.

Comment: Thanks for that, I feel stupid now :/. I couldn't see what was right in front of me!

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

all the default variables for switch cases named same. so if no option is selected php use value variable. change other default values accordingly at it would work.

```
<?php 

switch($_POST['rgroup1']) {
    case "rg1v1":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg1v2":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;`enter code here`
    case "rg1v3":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg1v4":
        $value = "Radio Group 1 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 1";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup2']) {
    case "rg2v1":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg2v2":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg2v3":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg2v4":
        $value2 = "Radio Group 2 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value2 = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 2";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup3']) {
    case "rg3v1":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v2":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v3":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg3v4":
        $value3 = "Radio Group 3 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value3 = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 3";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup4']) {
    case "rg4v1":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v2":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v3":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg4v4":
        $value4 = "Radio Group 4 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value4 = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 4";
}

switch($_POST['rgroup5']) {
    case "rg5v1":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 1 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v2":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 2 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v3":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 3 was selected.";
        break;
    case "rg5v4":
        $value5 = "Radio Group 5 - Value 4 was selected.";
        break; 

        default:
        $value5 = "No radio has been selected for Radio Group 5";
}


echo $value;
echo $value2;
echo $value3;
echo $value4;
echo $value5;

?>
```